# Detecting slightly bright areas (fawn of deer) in thermal images

Tags: c++, algorithm, opencv

I am looking into detecting slightly bright areas (fawns from the roe deer) in thermal images with openCV.

So far I managed to get some code that works somehow, but with to many **false negatives and false positives**.

I basically know my way around openCV. But from the algorithmic side I a not sure what the best solution should be to result in a most perfect detection.

So far I use a cascade of something like this

1. gaussion blur
2. some sore of hysteresis thesholding
3. blob detection

Code snipped:

```
    cv::GaussianBlur(gray, gray, cv::Size(gauss_size, gauss_size), 0);

    Mat threshUpper, threshLower;
    threshold(gray, threshUpper, mask_min, mask_max, cv::THRESH_BINARY);
    threshold(gray, threshLower, mask_min-mask_thresh, mask_max, cv::THRESH_BINARY);
    imshow("threshUpper", threshUpper);
    imshow("threshLower", threshLower);

    vector<vector<Point>> contoursUpper;
    cv::findContours(threshUpper, contoursUpper, cv::RETR_EXTERNAL, cv::CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);
    for(auto cnt : contoursUpper){
        cv::floodFill(threshLower, cnt[0], 255, 0, 2, 2, cv::FLOODFILL_FIXED_RANGE);
    }
    threshold(threshLower, out, 200, 255, cv::THRESH_BINARY);

    vector<vector<Point>> contours2clean;
    cv::findContours(out, contours2clean, cv::RETR_EXTERNAL, cv::CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);
    for(const auto& cnt : contours2clean) {
        double area = cv::contourArea(cnt);
        if ( area > cut_max_size || area < cut_min_size) {
            cv::floodFill(out, cnt[0], 0, 0, 2, 2, cv::FLOODFILL_FIXED_RANGE);
        }
        else {
            cv::floodFill(out, cnt[0], 255, 0, 2, 2, cv::FLOODFILL_FIXED_RANGE);
        }
    }

    std::vector<cv::KeyPoint> points;
    detector_->detect(out, points);
    cv::drawKeypoints(out, points, out, cv::Scalar(0, 0, 255), cv::DrawMatchesFlags::DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS);
```

I am looking for some advice for better approaches. Two images (raw and marked) are here:

[image: result_8]
[image: raw_8]
[image: result_12]
[image: raw_12]

Thanks!

Comment: I assume that you as a human are better at detecting those little ones. Please share some of your insight in English. I.e. describe why (especially in the upper two pictures) similarily bright areas are NOT considered. I think I can guess, but I want to make you approach your hunt for a solution from a hopefully different angle. Please describe other info than imaging which your software has access to. I imagine you could use the height over ground in meters? The resolution of the image, in square meters per pixel? (or feet of course)

Comment: @Yunnosch Thanks for your quick reply. Unfortunately that (the incapability of better explaining) is exactly why I reached out to you at stackoverflow. As a human I can see the spot, you are right on that. But how to translate "I see a heated spot" to openCV is my problem.

Comment: Then discuss additional information, i.e. beyond the picture.

Comment: related: https://forum.opencv.org/t/detecting-slightly-bright-areas-fawn-of-deer-in-thermal-images/3681

Comment: Do you only have a single frame to decide if it's a true positive? Using multiple frames might help for filtering out noise.

Comment: to suppliment Yunnosch's reasoning. to segment the correct point, you need to identify what makes it different. From what I can see, your point is a sharp bright 2D peak. which is like trying to find a 2D gaussian. that differentiates it from other brighter yet less sharp peaks

Comment: @mattlangford I will have more images, but the camera is possibly moving.